# How to decrypt a PKCS7 message

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I'm failing at decrypting some XML files in C#.

I know very little of cryptography, but from what I understand, I have a password protected certificate, containing both a private and a public key.

By applying the password to the certificate, I get the private key needed to decrypt files that I receive.

The messages I want to decrypt resides in a PKCS7 (CMS?) formatted file. I believe I need to parse the files, decrypt them, and then un-sign them.

I have little idea on how to do this. I have tried the tooling that I found was obvious candidates to help me get this task done, but I can't get it to work.

At this point, I really want to know; Is there something I'm not understanding? Or am I using the wrong tools for the job?

Here's some of my attempts in one bunch of code:

```
public string DecryptFailingExample()
{
    var content = File.ReadAllBytes("encryptedFileWithDataThatIWant.xml.enc");
    var cert = new X509Certificate2("certificateFile.pfx", "PasswordForFile");

    //This code didn't work. rsa.Decrypt would throw: "The length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key."
    //using RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    //var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(content, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1); //I tried all possible paddings - Nothing worked


    //So I tried this instead:
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
    signedCms.Decode(content); //Crash: ASN1 corrupted data; The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '13', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '16'.
    var ecms = new EnvelopedCms();
    
    //If I try to skip SignedCms and pass "content" directly to EnvelopedCms, I will get: "ASN1 bad tag value met."
    ecms.Decode(signedCms.ContentInfo.Content); //Crash: 
    ecms.Decrypt(new X509Certificate2Collection(cert));
}
```

This is what my message looks like, that I want to decrypt:

> -----BEGIN PKCS7-----
>
> MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHA6BAMIACAQAxggGEMIIBgAIBADBoMFExCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRF
> MSQwIgYDVQQKExtFdXJvcGVhbiBFbmVyZ3kgRXhjaGFuZ2UgQUcxHDAaBgNVB4MT
>
> etc
>
> 3nPyd3c9iGyKhWdQPPr/SRWB/l9bCjkla81MgTcj1rRGQyPJXpkyxpc9U4YYZnxt
> eHkcJMVWDw9ErThok8nh/7bkE4KbWBaLZAac+9occ4deDrlu0wAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
>
> -----END PKCS7-----

**EDIT:**
Here's another minimal example that doesn't work.

```
//Step 1: Load PKCS7 message from disk
var content = File.ReadAllBytes("encryptedFileWithDataThatIWant.xml.enc");

//Step 2: Load .pfx certificate from disk 
var cert = new X509Certificate2("certificateFile.pfx", "Password");

//Step 3: Create instance of EnvelopedCms
var ecms = new EnvelopedCms();

//Step 4: Add certificate for decoding
ecms.Certificates.Add(cert);

//Step 5: Decode the PKCS7 message
ecms.Decode(content); //Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'ASN1 bad tag value met.'
```

Apart from the .PFX file, I also do have a PEM file with the private certificate. It looks like this:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
> DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,915538553FEFBA6A98930E4BFFDA1E68
>
> Pk0FHxXNHukA62FSmuzzE+gqHgeauZr6z+lqTcbf55cakrQzHQOQUnR0w5kCFPPg
>
> etc
>
> L7U2cWJpbNsRNmBcTyH1WWJ4hYoCqdl9G6Zey4y/EQbZl1DKXtmIiLZSneF0VU9u
>
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I tried importing the key like this, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
var pem = File.ReadAllBytes("pemFile.pem");
var pemChars = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pem);
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportFromEncryptedPem(pemChars, "Password"); //System.ArgumentException: 'No supported key formats were found. Check that the input represents the contents of a PEM-encoded key file, not the path to such a file. (Parameter 'input')'
```

Comment: Yes, PKCS#7 specifies CMS, lookup the RFC. You should first PEM decode and then call `EnvolopedCms#Decode(binaryDerEncoding)` with the result. Usually messages are signed and then encrypted (if they are signed at all, of course).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for the tip. What would you expect the "PEM decode" part to look like, before EnvelopedCms.Decode(binaryDerEncoding)? I'll admit I have trouble translating what I believe should happen into code. In my head I should be able to: Load certificate (.PFX), applying the right password -> Extract Private Key from certificate -> Decrypt messages with the private key. But based on your answer, I guess I'm missing a step? Sorry if I sound confused. I am.

Comment: PKCS#7 is a binary encoding. PEM translates that to text using base 64 with header and footer lines (originally to make it possible to be used in S/MIME / email). The code you currently have seems to require the binary encoding. If you give the `Decode` function the text it will crash when it tries to binary decode the text. So you need a PEM parser which has been added to the latest versions of .NET (I know because I wrote some code for them some time ago already, open source). Of course any PEM parser will do, Bouncy Castle also contains one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT!

Thanks to @MaartenBodewes for putting me on the right track.
The file I wanted to decode was not in binary, but in text. Reading the file as text, and then converting to binary, was enough for it to work.

The working code looks approximately like this, and could be reduced even further for my specific case. As it is, it will handle PKCS7 and CMS tags + binary and text files.

```
public string Decrypt()
{
    var ecms = Read("encryptedFileWithDataThatIWant.xml.enc");
    var cert = new X509Certificate2("certificateFile.pfx", "Password");
    ecms.Decrypt(new X509Certificate2Collection{cert});
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ecms.ContentInfo.Content);
}

private static EnvelopedCms Read(string fileName)
{
    //Try read as binary
    var maybeFirstException = TryRead(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName), out var ecms);
    if (maybeFirstException is null)
    {
        return ecms;
    }

    //Otherwise read as text, convert to binary and try again
    var text = File
        .ReadAllText(fileName)
        .Replace("-----BEGIN PKCS7-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("-----BEGIN CMS-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("-----END PKCS7-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("-----END CMS-----", string.Empty);

    
    var binary = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        
    var maybeSecondException = TryRead(binary, out ecms);
    if (maybeSecondException is null)
    {
        return ecms;
    }

    throw new AggregateException("Tried to decode file as both binary and text, but both attempts failed", new List<Exception>
    {
        maybeFirstException,
        maybeSecondException
    });
}

private static Exception TryRead(byte[] bytes, out EnvelopedCms ecms)
{
    ecms = new EnvelopedCms();
    try
    {
        ecms.Decode(bytes);
        return null;
    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed the same and the ecms.ContentInfo.Content returns my payload along with unknown characters. Where have I been wrong?

Comment: I am still no expert on the topic, but what I found helpful in my situation apart from the gelp i got here, was to take a deeper look at the PKCS7 message i had in hand. Is your file binary? Or plain text? Does it have a PKCS7 header/trailer? Since you followed my example, there must be something thats different on your end. There is of course also the possibility that the PKCS7 message really does contains gibberish. Can you exclude that possibility?

Comment: My file have PKCS7 trailer. I tried decrypting same message using ChilkatDnCore. Unfortunately it was paid one.